# Openstack - How to create a new server in a specific project

Tags: openstack, microstack

I'm relative new to Openstack/Microstack platforms.

I have a Microstack environment with three projects:

- Two projects that created by default: "admin" and "service".
- One project that I created in my own: "myProject"

I noticed that when I am creating a new server using Microstack CLI, the server is automatically allocated in the "admin" Project, even if I specified (using --nic port-id) ports that belong to "myProject" project.

In contrast to creating new networks, subnetworks or ports, the command "microstack.openstack server create" have no "--project" flag.

Is there any way to create a new server in "myProject" project using Microstack CLI?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to take on the `myProject` identity. First, you need a user that has a role in `myProject`; let's call it `myUser`.

You can then log on **to the GUI** as `Myuser` and you will automatically be in `myProject`, if this is the only project where this user has a role.

In case `myUser` has roles in other projects, the GUI has a small menu, by default in the upper left corner, that allows you to switch projects.

On the **command line**, you need to change a few environment variables, namely OS_USERNAME, OS_PROJECT_NAME and of course OS_PASSWORD, before launching your server. Reference: https://docs.openstack.org/python-openstackclient/pike/cli/authentication.html.

Comment: I add the following commands to /etc/profile and reboot:
export OS_USERNAME=myUser
export OS_PROJECT_NAME=myProject
export OS_PASSWORD=myPassword

Unfortunately, the command "microstack.openstack token issue" still print me the token of admin user and not for myUser user. 

What did I missed?

Comment: Check what those variables are set to right before you execute the `microstack.openstack` command. I suppose another profile or RC file resets them.